# Correctness of 'afree' function in K&R

Tags: c, pointers

In the chapter *Address Arithmetic* the function `afree` is defined as follows:

```c
static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; // storage for alloc
static char *allocp = allocbuf;  // next free position

void afree(char *p) 
{
    if (p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
        allocp = p;
}
```

As far as I can see, the point of the if statement is to test whether `p` is within the bounds of the buffer.

However, if `p` is not within the bounds of the buffer, the comparision results in undefined behavior, doesn't it? Isn't it necessary to convert both pointers (`p` and `allocbuf`) to integers before doing the comparision?

Should the function not look like this or is this version even wrong?

```c
void afree(char *p) 
{
    uintptr_t p_int = (uintptr_t) p;
    uintptr_t a_start = (uintptr_t) allocbuf;
    uintptr_t a_end = (uintptr_t) (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE);

    if (p_int >= a_start && p_int < a_end)
        allocp = p;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if p is not within the bounds of the buffer, the comparison results in undefined behavior, doesn't it?

Yes.

> Isn't it necessary to convert both pointers (`p` and `allocbuf`) to integers before doing the comparison?

Yes this is the usual work around.

Even so, the arithmetic relationship of `>`, `<` and some `==` is not specified for such converted pointers.  Your updated code is still not certain work as desired, yet the result is at least not UB.

Consider two pointers `int_street:1` and `char_street:4` may point to the same physical address and compare equal as pointers, yet as integers `0x00010004, 0x00020004` are different.

---

Note that K & R was written along time ago, even before [Long Time Ago in a Galaxy Far Far Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) when `(u)intptr_t` was not defined.

C99 started `(u)intptr_t`.  They remain *optional* types, even though they are extremely commonly implemented.

Comment: You can not, in C.  Not all functions used by `C` like `free()` can be written _portably_  in C.  In _general_ there is no specified: "is my argument a valid pointer" test.  Some assumptions are made instead.

Comment: How can two pointers point to the same physical address yet be different as integers?

Comment: @AlexR in linear mapping, this does not happen.  In [segmented architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation), it is common.  Further, pointers of different types yet of the same bit pattern can refer to different physical addresses (See Harvard architecture).  C supports memory architectures much more novel than just linear - it is one of the reasons it it ported to so many places.

Comment: If you cast to integers, the comparison won't cause undefined behavior. Yet it is still possible that it will not correctly detect when the pointer is outside the array, and in that case you will very likely get undefined behavior somewhere else down the road.